# Add a nsstring at the end of attributed string in textview iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I have a text like "**Hello There**" which will be a attributed string  with red color. Then at the end of that attributed string I want to append a nsstring 'Who are you?' But whenever I append a nsstring, the whole string becomes normal nsstring and the property of the attributed string is being removed. My attempt so far:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello There"];
[attributeString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,[attributeString length])];

NSMutableAttributedString *previousAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:messageTextView.text];

[previousAttrString insertAttributedString: attributeString atIndex:location];
messageTextView.attributedText = previousAttrString;
messageTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15];

NSString *messageWithContact = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", messageTextView.text, @"Who are you?"];
messageTextView.text=messageWithContact;
```

What I did wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace the bottom lines

```
NSString *messageWithContact = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", messageTextView.text, @"Who are you?"];
messageTextView.text=messageWithContact;
```

with

```
NSMutableAttributedString *newString = messageTextView.attibutedText;
[newString appendAttributedString: [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"Who are you?"];
messageTextView.attibutedText = newString;
```

Comment: Edited first line should be: `NSMutableAttributedString *newString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:messageTextView.attributedText];`